# npm cors module not allowed access when specified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using the Cors() module and believe I am using it correctly on the server project:

```
...

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000'
};
...
app.use(cors());
...
app.post('/auth/instagram',  cors(corsOptions), function(req, res) {
     var accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
      .....
```

However, I am still receiving the following message in the console when the endpoint is hit by the client: 
(note - server on port 3000 and client on port 8000)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: There's the error reason: `A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.` it's likely that the OPTIONS request is being responded to with a *. you'll need to pass in the same options to `app.use(cors())`

Comment: Disable CORS in your browser.

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: Thanks for the help, @KevinB you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the following must be specified:

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));
```